# Reverse a string using a loop in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse, irvine32

I have recently been given an assignment from my professor to input a string and output it in reverse, he had help my class to write a code that prints each character of a string on a separate line which is shown below:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

;// .386
;// .model flat,stdcall
;// .stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data       ;// write your data in this section 
    prompt BYTE "Enter a string", 0ah, 0dh, 0
    text BYTE 101 DUP(?)

.code       ;// write your program here
main proc
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt
    call WriteString        ;prompt for input

    mov edx, OFFSET text    ; setup for text
    mov ecx, 100            ; max characters
    call ReadString

    mov ebx, 0
    mov edx, OFFSET text    ; setup of output
    call StrLength          ; get number of characters
    mov ecx, eax            ; setup the count register
L1:                     
    mov al, text[ebx]       
    call WriteChar          
    call Crlf               
    inc ebx             
    loop L1
main endp
end main
```

He then told us to manipulate the code so that it prints the string in reverse order, he had said something about using indirect addressing and decrement the address in the loop, can anyone help elaborate on this a little more, not looking for anyone to do the code for me, just some guidance

Comment: `ReadString` returns the length in EAX; you don't need to `strlen` it. 
 http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/readstring.htm

Comment: You already know how to loop forward and load 1 char at a time.  You can do the same thing backwards with `dec ebx` / `mov al, text[ebx]`.

Comment: @PeterCordes ive tried to swtich 'inc ebx' to 'dec ebx', but it only prints part of 'prompt' backwards

Comment: That obviously can't be the only change.  You need to start with EBX indexing the last byte of the string.  (Or one past that = string length, if you dec ebx before loading instead of after.)